# Wifi native with metro style app (Windows 8)

Tags: wifi, windows-8, windows-runtime

I would like to know if it is a way to to manage a wifi configuration with metro apps ?
Basically I want my application to list and retrieve information about all the available wifis the phone detects. I saw that it was possible so far using the wlanapi.h but I can't figure out how to use it in this metro style app context.

If you have any idea, please tell me.

Cheers

Comment: I doubt it is possible.  But I don't know for certain, so I'm not giving this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/7e937e68-9c52-4edf-9c7e-ff49f493d1a6) - it is not possible to list all wifi networks in range, but you can call [NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getconnectionprofiles.aspx) to list the known networks (or connection profiles) or [NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx) to access the one currently used for Internet access.